# File Path conflicts on GitHub with Unity

Tags: unity, file-format, filesystem, git

I am getting file path errors when a contributor is making commitments to GitHub. All of these errors are file path related or extra white space on the same lines.

This should be something in the .gitignore, but I can seem to locate it. Has anyone had similar issue with this?

[image: File Path Errors]
[image: Current .gitingnore]
[image: WhiteSpace Error]

Comment: Are you generating the `.csproj` and `.sln` files with VS Tools for Unity (http://unityvs.com/)? Then don't add those to the repository but let every user use their own copy.